# STM32 - How do I handle more than 14 filters?

Tags: stm32, can-bus

I am currently using the STM32F103RD processor, which has 14 available filters on the CAN1 bus.

I am connecting to a J1939 bus, and I need to monitor around 20 PGN's.  How do I handle setting up the 20 PGN's with only 14 filters available?

These 20 PGN's are not sequential, so I can't setup a specific range to allow.  These 20 may be all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

You have 14 filter banks, but each of those banks can match two distinct PGNs using identifier list mode (FBMx=0). So you can actually match up to 28 PGNs with this part! See section 24.7.4 of the [STM32F10x reference manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00171190.pdf) (page 655) for details.

If you need to match more than 28 PGNs, you have two options:

1. Pick sets of three or more PGNs and match each of those sets with a single mask-mode filter bank. To reduce the number of unwanted messages that are matched, you will need to pick the sets of matched PGNs carefully (i.e, keep the number of "don't care" bits in the resulting mask to a minimum). Since J1939 is *relatively* slow, though, filtering some unwanted messages out in software shouldn't be a huge burden.
2. Use a connectivity-line STM32 part, such as the STM32F107VC. These parts have double the number of CAN filter banks.

Comment: Perfect, I'll test it out using the List Identifier mode instead of the mask mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the list mode.  The tricky part is that PGNs need to be shifted around into a 32-bit header so that it can match the "CAN_RI0R" register to trigger an interrupt.  For example, I want to receive Engine RPM which is PGN 61444 (0xF004).  This needs to be converted into the following header:

0xC7802004

How to compute this:

1. Start with PGN 61444 (0xF004)
2. Shift it left by 8 bits so that it is in the correct J1939 Frame Format location.
3. OR it with 0x0018000000
4. Shift it left by 3 bits so that it matches the STM32 register locations for STID/EXID.
5. OR it with 0x4 to set the "Extended" bit indicating that it is an extended header.

The only caveat with this method, versus the mask mode is that as far as I know, you can only receive messages from one single ECU, since the source address is included in the header, and it must match exactly.  Meaning, you can only receive messages from the Engine ECU (0x00).  For example, 0x18F004XX, where XX is the source address.  When using the mask mode, you can ignore the Source Address bits, and receive the PGN from any ECU.